# Can we navigate a csv file using XPATH?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, csv, xpath

I need to validate CSV files in a .NET project. XPATH is used to navigate XML files. We are already using XPATH to validate xml files. Can we navigate a csv file using XPATH to carry out validation ?

Comment: XPath does not _validate_ XML files. Please explain what you mean by "validate XML" - or "validate CSV". Perhaps you [are really trying to do something that does not require XPath expressions for CSV files](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I am just using XPATH to get values of elements and attributes and thereby validate the content/values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already answered your own question:

> XPath is used to navigate XML files.

so: No.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't XPath works for XML based data only.

You might generate an XML file from your CSV file and validate it, then:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387090.aspx